# How to query limit 10 records from different where condition in MySQL or Go

Tags: mysql

Supposed I have below table with sample data as [this mysql link](https://dbfiddle.uk/xXUyQ72A), in Go porject, I get list of `users` by this sql `select * from users limit size offset (index-1)*size`

But now one of the 10 data items must have a a record whose `rank_value` greater than 0, in other words every page has 10 records, 9 records from `select * from users limit 9 where ran_value = 0` and 1 record from `select * from users limit 1 ＞ 0`,

I was stuck in this, How to query limit 10 records from different where condition in MySQL or Go,thanks so much for any advice.

```sql
CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT '',
    `age` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `rank_value` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `insert_at` bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

```golang
// init
db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:123456@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/test?charset=utf8")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}


// create dbr session
sess := dbr.NewConnection(db, nil)


// query list
var users []User
_, err = sess.Select("*").From("users").OrderBy("insert_at desc").Offset((Index - 1) * Size).Limit(Size).Load(&users)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}


for _, user := range users {
    fmt.Println(user.Name)
}
```

Comment: I added some paragraphs in your question and I got stuck on reading the second one... .  Please add some clear input data, and desired output   (The current DBFIDDLE looks nice, but does not have (or seem to have) a relation to your problem.

Comment: @Luuk Hi, I updated again, thanks for reading this.

Comment: I still do not get it, because every record in your DBFIDDLE has a rank_value >0 ?

Answer (score 1):

Combining LIMIT with UNION may be what you're looking for. This will allow you to retrieve `n` rows under `condition_a` and `m` rows under `condition_b`

```
(SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE condition_a LIMIT n)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE condition_b LIMIT m);
```

So for your case,

```
(SELECT * FROM users WHERE ran_val=0 LIMIT 9)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM users WHERE ran_val>1 LIMIT 1);
```

Comment: But what will happen if the `LIMIT 9` part is returning less than 9 records? I would suppose the original (weird?) question might expect to return always 10 records? (But I may be mistaken about that...)